# Displaying images from an EPUB file along with text using ITEM_DOCUMENT in Python

Tags: python, django, epub

I'm currently working on a Python project where I need to extract text and images from EPUB files and display them together. I'm using the ITEM_DOCUMENT method from the epublib library to extract the text successfully. However, I'm facing difficulties in extracting and displaying images alongside the text.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
class PDFtoBookCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'pdf_viewer.html'
    model = EBook
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context={}
        book = epub.read_epub("H:/Hexcoder/sellzzy/new2_developer02/tshirtbundle/static/epub/9781408855713.epub")
        
        
        epub.EpubBook.get_template = new_get_template
        epubObj= book.get_items_of_type(ebooklib.ITEM_DOCUMENT)
        epubObjList= list(epubObj)

        context['finalTextList'] = [xhtml_to_html(i.content) for i in epubObjList]
        return context
```

I'm able to retrieve the text content using the ITEM_DOCUMENT method, but I'm unsure how to extract and incorporate the images into the display. I've tried exploring the EPub library's documentation, but I couldn't find specific guidance on this matter.

Could someone please provide guidance on how I can extract images from the EPUB file using Python, and integrate them into my display alongside the extracted text? Any example code or pointers to relevant resources would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!